# IE7 position absolute issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Hi I'm having problem with a site in IE 10 Compatibility View (and in IE7 view as well, they are the same problem). Originally I have a background div behind the sidebar called .info-bg, and it's suppose to hide behind the sidebar .info-area, using position: absolute. However, in IE7, it looks like the background is not hidden. The only way to get it to hide is using position: static, which leaves an empty spot.
get the background to hide completely (like display none) is not an option because the right side loads more content as I scroll down. Which, without .info-bg just returns a blank space on the left. [Live Site Link](http://centilin.in)

[image: This is when I use position: absolute]
[image: This is when I use position: static]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can put this on the  section of your website:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

This will disable the Compatibility mode and stop messing your site.

Comment: But the problem occurs with IE7 as well, that is not something I can ignore unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

maikelsabido's answer is valid but only covers half of the issue. There is no point to supporting IE10 while it is rendering as IE7. So few people do this (my statistics are based on JavaScript/DOM object detection, not the user agent and therefore are extremely reliable, my site triggers an error 9999 if you try forcibly overriding the rendering mode) so just don't bother with IE10 rendering as IE7. However to test IE7 you should keep a copy of XP in a virtual machine.

That being said while Microsoft did a very small update to clean things up in IE7 it still has numerous issues. You'll want to use an *Internet Explorer Conditional Comment Style Sheet* which I have a full tutorial on how to implement at my site here...

http://www.jabcreations.com/web/css/ieccss

Once you've implemented an IECCSS for IE7 you don't need to use any hacks, just position it for IE7 specifically.

*That* being said your page layout doesn't look like you need CSS level 2 positioning at all. Even IE 5.0 has respectable CSS level 1 support *if* you know how to do basic layouts correctly, but don't feel bad because besides my site I always see people jumping head-first in their tutorials to use `position` instead of `float`. So if you want much more stable CSS in general and limit positioning for SEO purposes I recommend reading my CSS level 1 tutorial here as well...

http://www.jabcreations.com/web/css/nested-divisible-elements

If you do that it will limit your need to use CSS level 2 `position`. With your layout the only thing I was use position for is to keep the content at the top of the `body` element and then put the menus below the content in the code...and then use `position` to visually put the menus where they are on the page. If you disable CSS (e.g. Firefox's Web Developer toolbar does this easily or Firefox --> View [menu] --> Page Style [menu] --> No Style) *that* is how a search engine sees your page.

Also you really should fix your header elements. You have two `h4` and *then* several `h2` elements. You want to think of your page like a newspaper, yours currently has nothing about winning the war using `h1` but at the top of the front page the most important story is `h4` saving a cat from a tree in a retirement home. Understanding the semantics of HTML can be a powerful tool in combination with search engines in getting more people to find your site because you've made it easier for the search engine to understand the semantics of your content.

I hope this helps and if you have any other questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Add style rule position:relative to wraper id main-wrap like

```
#main-wrap{
    position:relative;
}
```

and the add the following CSS to the ".info-bg" div

```
.info-bg{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 600px; /* change according to your need */
    box-shadow: 0 0 73px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 4px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);  
}
```

Further you can check out this page to know how z-index property actually works - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-layers.php

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue you highlighted in IE7. But I need you to see this gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6607075 and try it on your side.

It's quite hard to fix on my side because I don't have your Wordpress theme.

Anyway, with regards to the gist (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6607075 )

- For the css, look at the code at line 108. For the `#info-wrapper`
- For the html, at line 94, I added a `<div id="info-wrapper">`

See if this fix the issue? If not, let me know in the comments.

--

Edit: You can download the files that I did test in IE7, [here at wetransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/041e3b33944115dca38b2b7b029a18d120130918095414/71edaf51d5a0a9246e8347d7fcd2b88d20130918095414/9db5a2)